# What is the meaning of "building to flip"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage

What is the usage of this phrase **building to flip**, I found it [here](http://www.computerweekly.com/feature/Dotcoms-building-to-flip-is-a-business-flop) and [here](http://www.forbes.com/sites/brockblake/2013/03/13/why-building-a-company-to-flip-is-recipe-for-failure/) and in many other places.

So what is to"to flip" means at the first place, the dictionary says

> turn over or cause to turn over with a sudden sharp movement

So is "building company to flip" means "building company to turn over"? it sounds confusing!

Comment: The first of your links put the usage in scare quotes (indicating that it's a neologistic/non-standard usage) which it effectively "defines" by explaining that entrepreneurs used to want to *found a company "built to **last**". These days, it appears, the concept has been overturned, and the intention is better summed-up as "build to **flip**"* (cf [***spin off***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/spin-off), convert to money by *floating or selling off*). The second link says *[I was] **focused on a lucrative exit** (building to flip)*.

Comment: Please don't answer in the comments, How can I accept an answer in a comment :)

Comment: I've never encountered the usage before (It may well be peculiar to AmE), and I have no idea whether there are *any* other instances besides the two you've cited. I don't see how you could struggle with the actual *meaning* (given the ***full context*** of the two examples), but I'm in no position to explain how the usage came about (and whether it has any direct relevance to earlier ***spin off***, for example).

Comment: ...since you're forcing me to dig deeper, note this definition for ***to flip*** - [*Finance. **to resell, especially quickly,** or to refinance, as a mortgage loan.*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/flip?s=t) I would say that's primarily an AmE usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the language of business, especially investment, "*flip*" often means acquire-modify-sell and relatively quickly (similar how you'd flip a pancake).

In real estate terminology one can often see "*flipping* a house" meaning "buying it, fixing it up and then selling it for a higher price than the cost of fixing and short-term financing".  Same can be done to a business, especially if its current management has allowed the business to stagnate, or even get out of hand.

Sometimes the property, be it a house or a business, just needs to be modified enough to make it attractive again to derive profit from the sale.  So, you can take the word '*modify*' in my first paragraph as "*fix up*".

Comment: Thanks, so I can assume that **building for flip** is for developing some product, make a company **NOT** for long term, but just to increase its value to sell it later.

Comment: @Mostafa36a2 - In the headlines you cite (Why Building a Company To Flip Is Recipe For Failure), that's *exactly* what it means.